# How to simplify nginx config when handling outdated browsers?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Example nginx.conf, I'd like to move conditional rewrite from location directives, but have no idea how:

```
# https://user-agents.net/browsers
map $http_user_agent $outdated {
    default 0;
    ...
}

server {
    ...
    location ~ (not-supported) {
        # empty
    }

    location / {
        if ($outdated = 1) {
            rewrite ^ /not-supported/index.html break;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rewrite` directive either at the `server` or at the `location` contexts. The difference is the [request processing phase](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases) where that `rewrite` directive will be processed (`NGX_HTTP_SERVER_REWRITE_PHASE` for the firest case, `NGX_HTTP_REWRITE_PHASE` for the second one). Avoid regular expressions whenever possible. When you use a `rewrite` directive at the `location` context, you should use `last` flag for the `rewrite` directive instead of `break` one to force new search of the location for the rewritten URI. I also recommend to make it internal to prevent direct access to the `/not-supported/` directory. So use either

```
location /not-supported/ {
    internal;
}

location / {
    if ($outdated = 1) {
        rewrite ^ /not-supported/index.html last;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

or

```
if ($outdated = 1) {
    rewrite ^ /not-supported/index.html;
}

location /not-supported/ {
    internal;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

You can have that `non-supported` directory with the `index.html` file inside either under your web root directory or anywhere else (for the last case you'll need to define a custom root for the `location /not-supported/ { ... }`). Make sure that rewrite rule do not interfere with any others may be present at the `server` context.

Answer (score -1):

Made it work by:

```
http {
# https://user-agents.net/browsers
map $http_user_agent $outdated {
    default 0;
    "~Opera"                                                    1; # Opera all
    "~MSIE"                                                     1; # MSIE all
    "~Trident/[1-7]\."                                          1; # MSIE all
    "~Chrome/(([1-9]{1})|([0-7]{1}[0-9]{1})|(8[0-6]{1}))\."     1; # Chrome 1.* - 86.*
    "~YaBrowser/(([1-9]{1})|([1-9]{1}[0-8]{1}))\."              1; # Yandex 1.* - 18.*
    "~Firefox/(([1-9]{1})|([0-7]{1}[0-9]{1})|(8[0-3]{1}))\."    1; # Firefox 1.* - 83.*
    "~EdgA?/(([1-9]{1})|([0-7]{1}[0-9]{1})|(8[0-6]{1}))\."      1; # Edge/MobileEdge 1.* - 86.*
    "~Version/(([1-9]{1})|([1-9]{1}[0-1]{1}))\."                1; # Safari 1.* - 11.*
}

server {
    listen       8080 default_server;
    root         /opt/app-root/src;

    if ($uri ~ /not-supported) {
        set $outdated 0;
    }

    if ($outdated = 1) {
        rewrite ^ /not-supported/index.html last;
    }

    location / {
    .......
```